# Transferência de Valores maiores que 65536 para variável DD error - Assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, 8086

Estou com uma certa dificuldade ao atribuir valores maiores que 65536 (16 bits), no meu exemplo de código atribuo o valor de 86400 (valor  de um dia) a uma variável com declaração de DD (arquitetura 32 bits) e o seguinte erro é apresentado ao tentar compilar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
.data

dia dd ?
re dd ?

.code

mov dia, 86400
mov re, 65536
mov ax, re
cmp ax, dia
jg programa
sub dia, re
programa:
hlt
```

Alguém sabe uma forma de conseguir executar essa ação?

Comment: O *emu8086* só consegue emular um processador de 16 bits, portanto, não é possível carregar um valor maior que 65535 em um registrador (erro de "*overflow*"). Você pode tentar compilar com o **fasm** (no menu assembler), mas a sintaxe do programa será diferente e você não conseguirá executá-lo no emulador. Outra opçao é utilizar um outro compilador (ex: [flat assembler](https://flatassembler.net) ou [NASM](https://www.nasm.us/)).